# React Native Background Download

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am about to build an app which locally stores multiple MySqlite *.db files. These are used to populate the app with data.

The app should regularly check if there is a newer version for one of these files and, if so, download it and replace the old version of the file.
This update process should happen in the background, while the app is inactive or even closed.

I have seen several plugins, which can be used to execute tasks in the Background (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task). This could be used to check for updates regularly, but the time limit of 30s on iOS will probably not be enough to download the *.db file. Also, the plugin forces a minimum Android API Version of 21.

My question is: Is it possible to poll for updates in the background AND download them, replacing old files?

Answer (score 4):

I found some useful plugins.

**1. react-native-fetch-blob**

https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Classes#rnfetchblobconfig

It has `IOSBackgroundTask` option.

```
RNFetchBlob
.config({
  path : dest_file_path,
  IOSBackgroundTask: true,
  overwrite: true,
  indicator: true,
})
.fetch('GET', download_url, {
  //some headers ..
})
.progress( (received, total) => {
    console.log('progress : '+ received + ' / ' + total);
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log('# The file saved to :', file_path);
})
```

By the way, it looks doesn't work properly.
Not sure if I miss something...

**2. react-native-fs**

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-

```
  const ret = RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: download_url, 
    toFile: dest_file_path,
    connectionTimeout: 1000 * 10,
    background: true,
    discretionary: true,
    progressDivider: 1, 
    resumable: (res) => {
      console.log("# resumable :", res);
    },
    begin: (res) => {
        // start event
    }, 
    progress: (data) => {
        const percentage = ((100 * data.bytesWritten) / data.contentLength) | 0;
        console.log("# percentage :", percentage);
    },
  });

  jobId = ret.jobId;

  ret.promise.then((res) => {
    console.log('Download finished.');
    RNFS.completeHandlerIOS(jobId);
    jobId = -1;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
    jobId = -1;
  });
```

It looks working well.
By the way, when I try download in background via push notification, it doesn't start download unless I open the app.
Anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: +1 to the RNFS example. From my experience RNFetchBlob is a shaky choice for two reasons. 1. It's not maintained. 2. it will block the JS thread during large file downloads which will render your app "frozen" until the process is over.

Comment: With rn-fetch-blob, do anyone download background on ios? I try to use it but sill doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

For download in the background, the best module I have used was [react-native-background-downloader](https://github.com/EkoLabs/react-native-background-downloader), which have pause, resume and the download percentage.

```
import RNBackgroundDownloader from 'react-native-background-downloader';

let task = RNBackgroundDownloader.download({
    id: 'dbfile',
    url: 'https://link-to-db/MySqlite.db'
    destination: `${RNBackgroundDownloader.directories.documents}/MySqlite.db`
}).begin((expectedBytes) => {
    console.log(`Going to download ${expectedBytes} bytes!`);
}).progress((percent) => {
    console.log(`Downloaded: ${percent * 100}%`);
}).done(() => {
    console.log('Download is done!');
}).error((error) => {
    console.log('Download canceled due to error: ', error);
});

// Pause the task
task.pause();

// Resume after pause
task.resume();

// Cancel the task
task.stop();
```

This module is also suitable for iOS and you can download multiple files in a row in the background.

Comment: react-native-background-downloader has been archived :(